# Creating chart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, charts

I know about asp.net charts but I want to create graphs in a different style, like:

[image: graph]

I've tried in asp.net but I'm unable to do this. I think this some API of google or something similar might help. If anyone knows how I can create this style of charts, please help me (preferable with examples).

I got this sample from http://www.brecorder.com/

Comment: have you tried using JQuery? check this link:http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ChartsDemo/examples/chart/Area%20-%20Aggregate.html

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.brecorder.com/ use flash object for their chart. You can use [Open Flash Chart on asp.net](http://mitchelburton.com/tutorials/open-flash-charts-for-asp-net/) or use javascript chart like [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/). Look at [demo charts](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/).

Comment: Sir Where can i find the source of High charts to link with my database

Comment: are you kidding me? just visit http://www.highcharts.com/ and you will get the link to download

Comment: sir can i apply these styles on asp.net chart simply